# Mapbox Geocoder gives index error (internal server error)

Tags: python, django, mapbox, geocoding

I'm using mapbox geocoder for finding latitude and longitude from zip-codes.Problem is it sometimes work just fine and somtimes doesn't work at all.When it doesn't work,it return `index error out of bounds`,but in my terminal also shows `internal server error`. What can be done it this situation?

My code is bellow:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SingleCenterDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        zip_code = self.object.center.zip_code
        geocoder = Geocoder(access_token=mapbox_access_token)
        response = geocoder.forward(str(zip_code))
        response = response.geojson()['features'][0]
        resp = response.get('center')
        geo = [resp[0],resp[1]]
        context['geo'] = geo
        return context
```

And the problem is in line `response = response.geojson()['features'][0]` becouse when it works good,when I print this line it shows dict like this

`{'text': '53-334', 'context': [{'text': 'Wrocław', 'wikidata': 'Q1799', 'id': 'place.8365052709251970'}, {'short_code': 'PL-DS', 'text': 'Dolnośląskie', 'wikidata': 'Q54150', 'id': 'region.25860'}, {'short_code': 'pl', 'text': 'Poland', 'wikidata': 'Q36', 'id': 'country.340'}], 'geometry': {'coordinates': [17.026519, 51.096412], 'type': 'Point'}, 'center': [17.026519, 51.096412], 'type': 'Feature', 'relevance': 1, 'bbox': [17.024936, 51.095263, 17.028411, 51.09752], 'place_name': '53-334, Wrocław, Dolnośląskie, Poland', 'place_type': ['postcode'], 'properties': {}, 'id': 'postcode.5334805015388220'}`

when it  doesn't work it prints nothing (thats this index error)

So my question is,can anything be done to solve this? I mean,if this sometimes work and sometimes does not then its probably mean that for some zip-codes it
cannot find latitude and longitude,but maybe is there some workaround? Or maybe problem is much more trivial and I simply did someting wrong? (I can even imagine it is some Django problem beocuse of this internal server error)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have founded solution and it is much simpler than i thought.Sometimes zip code it isn't enough.So instead of zip code,you have to pass to `geocoder.forward()` entire address,like 'Szaserów Warszawa 04-141`
then it should works pretty well.